# In .md files, does HTML h1 and markdown # work the same?

Tags: html, github, markdown, readme

I am learning how to make README.md files stylish and easy to read. I am also trying to learn good coding, GitHub, and repository structuring practices.

I found that I could style README.mds using HTML. However, I am a bit confused about how HTML interacts with .md files.

For example, does `<h1>Project Title</h1>` work the same as `#Project Title` in a README.md?

Additionally, is it considered bad practice to use HTML to format a README.md? I noticed a lot of my friends repositories do not use HTML.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Both `<h1></h1>` and `#` seem to work the same in README.md. However, I am worried I am not following standard practice or am making my README.mds incompatible with other markdown features (or something like that).

I am so new to GitHub that I can't tell if I am doing something wrong by using HTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, yes, a top-level heading is equivalent to `h1`.  Markdown is designed to be a shorthand for HTML and so it has a lot of correspondence.  In addition, you can embed HTML in your Markdown file to do things that Markdown itself can't.

However, having said that, if you're writing Markdown, it's best to use the Markdown features wherever possible.  Those will be more familiar to people and generally more flexible, substantially easier to read in plain text, and in some cases, such as READMEs and documents on GitHub, certain tags, as well as JavaScript and CSS, are restricted for security purposes.  In addition, if you're converting Markdown to another format with a tool like pandoc, much of that HTML won't transfer.

Thus, you'll have more success if you think about Markdown as an independent document language you use to write text, where you may, from time to time, embed HTML to do very specific things, rather than writing a full Markdown-HTML hybrid.  When you think about using Markdown as a document language primarily for text, and not a language that has support for formatting documents (e.g. alignments, colours, layout, etc.), then it becomes easier to write Markdown documents that work in a wide variety of contexts.  Since your README is designed to basically communicate ideas using text, perhaps with a few images, that approach will help you write more typical Markdown.